# I can't import ngResource into my App

Tags: angularjs, node.js, webpack, angular-resource, angular1.6

I have an app made with **Angular (angular 1.6)** and **NodeJS**, and I can't import the angular library **ngResource** into my app. These are the steps I did:

1: in command line I input `npm install --save angular-resource`

2: in app.js:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import ngResource from 'angular-resource';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import Components from './components/components';



angular.module('myApp', [
  uiRouter,
  Components,
  ngResource
])
.component('homePage', HomeComponent)
.service('AirportsService', AirportsService)
.service('CheapFlightService', CheapFlightService)
```

and after doing that, I get this error in the browser:

```
angular-resource.js:444 Uncaught TypeError:
```

angular.module(...).info is not a function

Comment: I think you should use @NgModule() instead of angular.module. angular.module is from angular1 and I am not sure that function still available in angular 4.

Comment: Hi Vignesh, I am using angular 1.6 to this project

Comment: can you post your index.html code? I don't remember using import statements with angular1 but it's been a lot of time since I worked in it. I am not sure whether the syntax above is right for angular1. post your index.html as well to get more info.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are running into compatibility problem with angularjs 1.6.x modules.

Make sure the angular and the associated modules are of same version in `package.json`.

With `angular@1.6.7` and `angular-resource@1.6.7`, the angular1 components does work fine for me.